# Understanding PCA inverse transform python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to achieve PCA inverse transform python using the loop on my dataset.
Just want to understand the logic behind the function. Any pointers/suggestion would be really helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# load the data
digits = load_digits()

# project the 64-dimensional data to a lower dimension
pca = PCA(n_components=15, whiten=False)
data = pca.fit_transform(digits.data)

# use grid search cross-validation to optimize the bandwidth
params = {'bandwidth': np.logspace(-1, 1, 20)}
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), params, cv=5, iid=False)
grid.fit(data)

print("best bandwidth: {0}".format(grid.best_estimator_.bandwidth))

# use the best estimator to compute the kernel density estimate
kde = grid.best_estimator_

# sample 44 new points from the data
new_data = kde.sample(44, random_state=0) 

new_data = pca.inverse_transform(new_data)
```

Want to achieve this with the simple loop is that possible?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.inverse_transform

*Above Question is just to clear concepts only*

Comment: You refer to "the loop" twice, once before and after the code. What does that mean? Conceptually, PCA computes and applies an affine transformation such that the new "components" are all orthogonal. The inverse function undoes that transformation. At least, it undoes it as best as it can. In most cases, PCA is used to reduce the dimensionality of the data. In your example, you are restricting the number of transformed components to 15.

Comment: Check the `sklearn` source: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L159

Comment: (Note that the PCA inverse transform is not necessarily unambiguous.)

Comment: my main purpose is to understand how inverse transform works internally and trying to replicate with just with loop.

Comment: This question already has an answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com

Comment: Perfect,  thanks @Hapalop for sharing the link!